# Single.Create()...blockingGet() hangs in RxJava 2.1.3 when using Android/Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rx-java, rx-java2

When using the following pattern to synchronously get data from Firebase Realtime Database:

```
String s = Single.create(new SingleOnSubscribe<String>() {
    @Override
    public void subscribe(SingleEmitter<String> e) throws Exception {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("path").orderByChild("child").equalTo("xyz").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        e.onSuccess("Got it");
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        e.onError(databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
}
}).blockingGet();
```

It will hang and create an ANR error.  If I use the same Firebase "innards" outside of the Single, it fires just fine.  The Single without the Firebase code inside also will fire, so it seems there is some incompatibility between the two.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase delivers events on ui thread, waiting for result with `blockingGet` deadlocks it. In my opinion you should rethink app logic and subscribe without blocking with `subscribe(SingleObserver)`

Comment: That doesn't work because the `blockingGet` is still executed and is still blocking the main thread, preventing the firebase event callback's execution.

Comment: @akarnokd i agree - given there is no way to pass executor to `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, `blockingGet` on ui thread will always deadlock. Either get rid of blocking or call all the code presented in question from non-ui thread

Comment: Indeed that's the situation. Based on [discussion](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5576#issuecomment-326072788) on the RxJava issue list, where this comes from, the OP seems to really block the main thread for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating your own Single, You should use `DisposableSingleObserver` in `subscribeWith`. Secondly, you shouldn't be calling blockingGet() like that. The reason is by default the `Single or any observable/Processor/Flowable` you create will be subscribed (run its operations on main thread) and observe on *main thread*. `BlockingGet()` causes the mainThread to pause. It's like executing `Thread.sleep()` on Main Thread. This always ends in a disaster.

The best option for you would be to rethink the logic you are trying to put in to the code. Since the Firebase operations are Async by nature, you should adapt your code to async pattern.

Anyways you can do something like the following to achieve what seems likes you might be trying to do. Note that I wrote the following code here so it might have syntactical errors.

```
   Single.create(new SingleOnSubscribe<String>() {
        // your firebase code
    @Override
        public void subscribe(SingleEmitter<String> e) throws Exception {

  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("path").orderByChild("child").equalTo("xyz").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            e.onSuccess("My String");
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            e.onError(databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
       }
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedular.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidThread.mainThread()) // if you aren't doing intensive/long running tasks on the data you got from firebase
    .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<String>() { 
         public void onSuccess(String myString) {
               mMyString = myString;
         }
         public void onError(Throwable t) {
            Timber.e("error in fetching data from firebase: %s", t);
         }
     });
```