# How can RxJava2 return the result from onSuccess in a method it was called from?

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java2

```
rxjava:2.1.14
rxandroid:2.0.2
Android Studio 3.2 Canary
```

I have the following method that will retrieve a cursor of sorted rows.

However, this method needs to return the cursor. However, there is no way
I can return the cursor as the onSuccess method returns void.

Just wondering how can I get the cursor from the onSuccess and return it from the method?

```
public Cursor queryAllInsects(String sortOrder) {
        insectStorageInteractorImp.getAllSortedInsects(sortOrder)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Cursor>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Cursor cursor) {
                        return cursor; /* anyway I can return the cursor in this method */
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    }
                });
    }
```

InsectStorageInteractorImp.kt

```
override fun getAllSortedInsects(sortOrder: String): Single<Cursor> {
    return Single.fromCallable {
        insectStorageImp.queryAndSort(sortOrder)
    }
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: You can call `Single.blockingGet`. But I strongly discourage that, it defeats the whole point of having Rx in the first place.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45978642/7470253) (and the question, for that matter) for a more detailed explanation of why what you are trying to do is a bad idea.

Comment: Why do you need to return a cursor? What will you do with it? You're better off returning a Singlr<Cursor> and doing everything you need to with that cursor in the onSuccess callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't (well, technically you can, but it would break the point of using RxJava and would be strictly worse than just changing `getAllSortedInsects` to return a `Cursor` (don't consider this to be a suggestion to change `getAllSortedInsects` to return a `Cursor`)).

But in Kotlin you can do something which *looks* very much like returning a `Cursor` and can be used similarly with coroutines:

```
public suspend fun queryAllInsects(sortOrder: String): Cursor =
    insectStorageInteractorImp.getAllSortedInsects(sortOrder)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .await()
```

See https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md for coroutines and https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/reactive/kotlinx-coroutines-rx2 for RxJava2 integration.

Alternately, don't bother with RxJava2 at all and use coroutines for all asynchrony.